# Component $onInit() can't see the variable in controller - angularjs 1.6.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components

I am writing angularjs app in 1.6.x... and I am having issues with component() where $onInit() can not see any var defined...

every var is undefined

here is my code..

```
angular.module('carFilter', []).
        component('carFilter', {
            controller: function (carFactory, $http) {
                this.service = carFactory; 
                this.updatedObj = {};
//when i put breakpoint here on chrome, i can see the factory obj.. but..
//when it goes to oninit, init can not see this obj



            this.$onInit = function () {
                    this.testing = 'a';
                    console.log(this.service); //th

                    loadFilter().then(function (result) {

                    updateFilter(result)
                });
            };

            function loadFilter() {
               //$http here to return promise 
            }
            function updateFilter(responseData) {
               //using response data to update i wanted to update the this.updatedObj
               this.updatedObj = responseData;
//but here, when this function is triggered, every object is undefined...
//I tried to put this.sercie and this.updatedObj in $onInit(), but it was still getting UNDEINFED.... 
//it could not see this.testing either...
//how can i update object in the controller??
            }
       },
       templateUrl: 'someURL'
});
```

thank you in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enter the $onInit function(){}, this now refers to the $onInit, so it becomes an issue of allowing the variable this from the controller to be passed in.

I know a lot of people declare vm or ctrl depending on who you learned it from on the first line of your controller.

i.e.

```
var ctrl = this;
ctrl.service = carFactory;

ctrl.$onInit = function() {
    console.log(ctrl.service);
}
```

Comment: thanks, I changed my code to have var ctrl = this; and used ctrl.service instead. 'ctrl' definitely points to the controller now, but the property of ctrl, for example, ctrl.service is still undefined in $onInit().. any tips or insights??

Comment: I've not really been a fan of assigning the factory to a variable inside the controller, what happens if you just console.log(carFactory)?  It could be an injection issue, is carFactory a .factory on carFilter?

Comment: wow.. nevermind.. it did fix it. Thank you so much. I've been battling over this for 4 hours... I guess i did not have a deep understanding of what "this" does..

Comment: I used factory b/c i had to share the data.. there is another component that shares the data with carFilter, and based on the filter, the other component draws the chart using chartjs. I am very new to angularjs and I just heard factory is used to share the data. If there is better way of sharing data between two components, please let me know! :)

Comment: factories/services are a great way to hold and share data between components.  It sort of depends on how you want to get the data.  A service is more like a constructor that can be invoked with 'new', while factories are generally used as a list of methods that get called by invoking the factory.  I use factories to get data from external or serverside sources, while services are for reusable contructors with methods that are not included from server side data.

This isn't a bad writeup
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/07/service-vs-factory-once-and-for-all.html

Answer (score 0):

With Angular 1.6, variables defined outside a method in a controller are ignored. You should also define all methods on the object `this` in the controller.

```
angular.module('carFilter', []).
    component('carFilter', {
        controller: function (carFactory, $http) {
            this.$onInit = function () {
                this.service = carFactory; 
                this.updatedObj = {};
                this.testing = 'a';
                console.log(this.service);

                this.loadFilter().then(function (result) {
                    this.updateFilter(result)
                }.bind(this);
            };

            this.loadFilter = function() {
               //$http here to return promise 
            };

            this.updateFilter = function (responseData) {            
                this.updatedObj = responseData;
            };
        },
        templateUrl: 'someURL'
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

In a function `this` references whichever object invokes the function, which isn't necessarily your component.

To make sure your `this` object in `$onInit` references your component you can either bind it explicitly to the component `this`:

```
this.$onInit = function () {
    ...
};
this.$onInit.bind(this);
```

or set a variable to your component's `this` and access it in `$onInit` using closure:

```
var vm = this;

this.$onInit = function () {
    vm.testing = 'a';
    console.log(vm.service); //th

    loadFilter().then(function (result) {
        updateFilter(result)
    });
};
```

The same goes for your `updateFilter` function.